# Uploading 5000kb pdf file or image in PHP not working

Tags: php, html, file-upload

I have a problem. I can't store the file that I am uploading on my website . It has a 5000kb size and it is a pdf.

Here's my code

```
if(!empty($_FILES['image-files-gallery']['tmp_name'])){
    if($_FILES['image-files-gallery']['size'] < 1000000){
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image-files-gallery']['tmp_name'],"uploaded_files/uploaded_files_gallery_images/" . $_FILES['image-files-gallery']['name']);
    }
    else{
        echo "File size is very big";
    }
}else{
    //nothing
}

if(!empty($_FILES['file-files-gallery']['tmp_name'])){
    if($_FILES['file-files-gallery']['size'] < 1000000){
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file-files-gallery']['tmp_name'], "uploaded_files/" . $_FILES['file-files-gallery']['name']);
    }
    else{
        echo "File size is very big";
    }
}
else
{
        //nothing
}
```

Comment: What's the output coming? When you say "not working" you should be clear in expecting what and what's happening.

Comment: why is this tagged as "pdo"? it should also be tagged as "file-upload" if anything. Unless you meant to use the "pdf" tag.

Comment: check your max upload settings; most likely that's the reason here.

Comment: maybe you've to check `upload_max_filesize = 10M` and `post_max_size = 40M`. [check this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/change-the-maximum-upload-file-size)

Comment: Also, make sure you have permission to the directory you're trying to move them to, and sufficient space there.

Comment: @Paul Kevin,  Consider the comment posted by  `Alexandre Painchaud`. Both the directives should be set to 5M or above. Also check with your host if MIME Type `application/pdf` has extension set to `pdf`

Comment: Yep Thank you @AlexandrePainchaud . That helped me

Comment: @PaulKevin Glad to help you